# count of the column names in phpmyadmin (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

this seems stupid, but I really don't know this thing.
Today, I am in need to get number of properties in a mysql table (in phpmyadmin).
Can I get the count of the column names in phpmyadmin (mysql)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that You can write sql query in phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = '<table_name>'
```